# Can I make stack download the .hs source code to its library directory?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

For example, if I do this operation to `base`, there should be a `Prelude.hs` in `~/.stack/programs/platform/ghc-x.y/lib/ghc-x.y/base-x.y`, along with `Prelude.hi`. So `stack unpack` wouldn't do as it unpacks the source code in the current directory.

Alternatively, can I extract GHC core from a `.hi` (`ModIface`)? That way I don't need the source code.